# how to check first person in queue with array_shift function in php

Tags: php

After a person has placed all the desired articles on the tray, they go to the back of the queue at the till. To simulate this, we are going to make a tillQueue object, which will then be linked to a till. Think of appropriate code for the firstPersonInQueue method (Tip: look at the array_shift function)

How to can implement it with array shift function:

```
<?php

class tillQueue
{
// tillQueue is a list of persons
    private $tillQueue;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function constructor()
    {
        $tillQueue = array();
    }

    /**
     *Person joins the back of the queue
     * @param person
     */
    public function joinsBackOfQueue($person)
    {
        $this->tillQueue[] = $person;
    }

    /**
     *If there is a queue, remove the first Person from
     *the queue and return.
     *If there is no one in the queue, this returns null.
     * @return First person in queue or null
     */
    public function firstPersonInQueue()
    {
    // method body omitted
    }

    /**
     *Method checks whether there are persons in the queue.
     * @return Whether or not a queue exists
     */
    public function thereIsAQueue()
    {
        return sizeof($this->tillQueue) > 0;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: it's like an interview exercise. you should attempt to answer ya know. if you've hit a stump, then you can show it in here. not ask to write everything

Comment: and you already got clue by the way [`array_shift`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: Can someone please help me with a firstPersonInQueue() method? I am a beginner,please help me!!

Comment: This looks like an assignment in school. Is it?

Comment: Start by look at what array_shift() actually does: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an assignment in school, But it would be definitely helpful for many.

what array_shift() actually does: [php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php – bestprogrammerintheworld](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php%20%E2%80%93%20bestprogrammerintheworld)

The below code must do your job:

```
return array_shift($this->tillQueue);
```